# How to configure limit of response size from Tomcat8 server

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, server, httpresponse

I am looking for how to configure or verify limits of response size a Tomcat 8 server can support. I have some GET apis which can return a very large response. I see whenever response is like 50MB or 100MB there is no problem, but sometime it could be much larger than this size. Could be in GBs. Whenever that happens, api is failing. Can someone suggest that at least for Tomcat level, it shouldnt fail. For the other layers e.g. load balancer or web server I will look into it.  I know there is request size limit which could be configured by maxHttpHeaderSize. But I am looking for response size.

Comment: If there are other layers in between: How do you know that this is a problem on the Tomcat side, and not on load-balancer or webserver side? Based on that infrastructure, this question sounds suspiciously like a system administration (and configuration) question, rather than a programming question as defined in [help/on-topic]

Comment: @OlafKock -  Sure but I want to know if Tomcat itself can object, if lets say a response of 2GB ended up. Is there any limit on response size from tomcat side?

Comment: Same here for Tomcat 9 and 10